# Compare the data of excel sheet with related data in neo4j

Tags: excel, neo4j

We migrated the data from RDBMS TO NEO4J in excel format.
We have around 100000 records in an excel sheet, Using that excel sheet we created data in neo4j. Now, we want to compare the data of excel with the nodes data in neo4j.

There are some fields in excel sheet that are duplicate means that particular field value is used multiple time but in neo4j its just 1 time.(Using merge)

Is there any way to compare and verify that large amount of data.
So , that we can know we haven't lost any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a concrete general answer (like a tool that will do that for you), since it will have to depend on knowledge of the spreadsheet data structure, the neo4j data model, and how you want the two to correspond.

But perhaps you can do a sanity check by extracting from the spreadsheet information about:

- how many nodes (of each label) you expect
- how many relationships (of each type) you expect

and comparing that with what the neo4j DB actually contains. If the numbers match exactly, then you can have some confidence that your data is intact. You can also spot-check a few nodes to see if they have the expected relationships, and check if those nodes and relationships have the right data.

To get the number of nodes of each label, and relationship of each type, you can use the APOC procedure [apoc.meta.stats](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#meta-graph):

```
CALL apoc.meta.stats() YIELD labels, relTypesCount
RETURN *
```

Here is a sample result:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════╕
│"labels"                              │"relTypesCount"                       │
╞══════════════════════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"Movie":76,"Class":2,"Partner":1,"Con│{"ACTED_IN":344,"REVIEWED":18,"WROTE":│
│tract":2,"Person":275,"Claim":2}      │20,"PRODUCED":30,"CLAIMANT":2,"FOLLOWS│
│                                      │":6,"DIRECTED":88,"POLICY_HOLER":2}   │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I only chose to `YIELD` 2 of the results from that procedure; you may want to look at the others to see what additional checks you may want to do.